Visio Container FillForegnd not taking effect
I'm controlling Visio from Python using win32com and with good results overall so far.  After a recent update to my code, container header fills are no longer taking effect.  The code I'm using:
class Container(Shape):
  v_app: Application
  def __init__(self, caption: str, items: list, header_fill: str=None, font: Font=None) -> None:
    # select items for container:
    window = self.v_app.app.ActiveWindow
    selection = window.Selection; selection.DeselectAll()
    for item in items:
      selection.Select(item.shape, 2) # visSelect = 2
    # drop and format container:
    self.shape = self.v_app.page.DropContainer(self.v_app.doc.Masters.ItemU("Classic"), selection)
    super().__init__(self.shape)
    self.shape.Text = caption
    if font:
      self.set_font(font)
    else:
      self.set_font(self.v_app.font4)
    if header_fill:
      self.shape.Cells("FillForegnd").FormulaForceU = header_fill
    self.shape.ContainerProperties.FitToContents()

The resulting shapesheet value looks correct:

However the header fill does not change from the default white.  If I use the Visio GUI, I am able to update the fill color successfully.

I created a stand-alone program to isolate the issue from my code base:
import win32com.client as w32

app = w32.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
app.Window.SetWindowRect(10, 10, 2000, 1000)
doc = app.Documents.Open(r"C:\Users\hankb\OneDrive\Documents\Python\projects\visio_test\junk.vsdx")
# doc = app.Documents.Add("junk.vsdx")
page = doc.Pages.Add()
b1 = page.DrawRectangle(1, 5, 2, 4.5); b1.Text = "Box 1"
b2 = page.DrawRectangle(1, 4, 2, 3.5); b2.Text = "Box 2"
win = app.ActiveWindow
sel = win.Selection
sel.Select(b1, 2)
sel.Select(b2, 2)
con = page.DropContainer(doc.Masters.ItemU("Classic"), sel)
con.Cells("FillForegnd").FormulaForceU = "RGB(189, 215, 238)" # RGB(0,255,0)"
con.Text = "Container"
pass

The output from the short program:

The code below solved my issue:
con = page.DropContainer(stencil.Masters.ItemU("Classic"), sel)
con_header = con.Shapes[1]
con_header.Cells("FillForegnd").FormulaForceU = "RGB(189, 215, 238)"
con.Text = "Container"


What do you mean as container header fills are no longer taking effect? Can you share some screensot or text description?

I added a screenshot of the container.  Although the shapesheet value looks correct the container does not display with the selected fill color.  Changing the color in the Visio GUI works correctly.

Container consist of few shapes. You need define sub-shape 'header'

When you change color via user interface, it taking effect for container shape (top level shape) and for all its sub-shapes. With code you can change only shape which is selected! Check my answer for same thread

Thank you, again, @Surrogate.  I'm using the code below now and it is working properly:  con = page.DropContainer(stencil.Masters.ItemU("Classic"), sel)
con_header = con.Shapes[1]
con_header.Cells("FillForegnd").FormulaForceU = "RGB(189, 215, 238)"
con.Text = "Container"

Here's the solution.  Thanks to Surrogate.
con = page.DropContainer(stencil.Masters.ItemU("Classic"), sel)
con_header = con.Shapes[1]
con_header.Cells("FillForegnd").FormulaForceU = "RGB(189, 215, 238)"
con.Text = "Container"

